# Binding ContextActions MenuItem with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have a problem in binding a `ReplyCommand` to a `MenuItem` in the `ContextAction`.

```
<ListView x:Name="listDictionaries" ItemsSource="{Binding Dictionaries}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                            FontSize="18"
                            FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <MenuItem Text="Set as default"
                       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference listDictionaries}, Path=BindingContext.SetDefaultCommand}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I associated to this view a ViewModel and in the code of the page I wrote:

```
DictionaryListViewModel vm;

public DictionaryList(DictionaryListViewModel model)
{
    vm = model;
    BindingContext = vm;
    
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await vm.Init();
}
```

The `Init()` reads from the database a list of `Dictionary` items (`Dictionary` is my class not the NET class). In the associated ViewModel I created this command:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task SetDefault(Dictionary dictionary)
{
    Message = "Set as default: " + SelectedDictionary.Name;
}
```

When I run the application, I can see a black screen but the items are there. As you can see, I can click on one item an display the value of the cell in an `DisplayAlert` but the binding is not working.

[image]

If I remove the `ViewCell.ContextActions`, the list displays the item as expected.

What is correct way to bind the `ReplyCommand` to the `MenuItem`?

### Update

I followed the example in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand) but I still have issues.

The only way I found to have this `MenuItem` working is to use `Clicked` and then in the code behind invoke a function.

```
<MenuItem Text="Set as default"
            Clicked="OnSetAsDefault"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

and then in the code

```
public async void OnSetAsDefault(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
    Dictionary dictionary = (Dictionary)mi.CommandParameter;
}
```

It is working but at this point I don't understand the meaning of the `Command` or `RelayCommand`.

Comment: Did you ever raise a GitHub issue based on Liyun Zhangs answer?

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your problem in my project on the windows platform. But it worked well in the android platfrom.

It seems a new issue when you use the `[RelayCommand]` attribute on a method which needs a parameter. If you delete the parameter, it will work. Such as:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task SetDefault()
{
    Message = "Set as default: " ;
}
```

And you can also use the ICommand instead of the RelayCommand just as the official sample which used the **INotifyPropertyChanged interface** instead of the **ObservableObject class** did. You can check the official sample about [Binding ContextActions MenuItem with MVVM](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/e6a1b3e822a1fff334483c4f39c696fa07926aca/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos/ViewModels/MonkeysViewModel.cs#L9).

**I have tested using ICommand of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface instead of the RealyCommand of the ObservableObject. It worked.**

In addition, you can also try to post a new issue for [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm in MAUI](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues) on the github.